# How are the values of stored firefox credit cards encrypted? And how does one decrypt those?

Tags: encryption, passwords, cryptography, web-browser, firefox

While researching about the safety of web browsers I made my own program that can decrypt stored credentials, cookies, and other information of different browsers to see for myself how easy it is.

Though when trying to decrypt the credit card information of firefox using the same method that I used for the login decryption it didn't work.

After some more research, I encountered this post that states firefox credit cards and logins are encrypted differently: [How does Firefox protect Logins and Credit Card Data?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/254250/how-does-firefox-protect-logins-and-credit-card-data)

*How exactly does the encryption* process differ from one of the login credentials? And how does one decrypt those values?